# IOS -> Audio Queue Services : Memory leaks with m4a or MP4 files

Tags: iphone, stream, core-audio, mp4

My problem:

I have memory leaks with "`Audio File Stream Services Reference`" API.

How reproduce the bug :

- Used this audio streamer sample (https://github.com/mattgallagher/AudioStreamer)
- Play `m4a` or `mp4` file
- Stop Player
- Memory leaks occur when this function is called : `AudioFileStreamClose`

For information :
- I have no memory leaks with `MP3` or `AAC` files

- File used : Apple sample file (`sample_mpeg4.mp4` - http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1425))

Why `AudioFileStreamParseBytes` generated memory leaks only with `m4a` or `mp4` files format?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we are not customer support for your favourite company](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/).